# Why getchar() behaves differently?

Tags: c, getchar

I found `getchar()` is behaving differently in some situations.
In the following code, it devours the newline character in the input.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// copy input to output; 1st version
int main()
{
    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
    {
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

The input and output in the terminal looks like this.

```
j
j
b
b
asdf
asdf
ashdfn
ashdfn
```

It exactly duplicates the input and ignores the newline character in the input due to return key I pressed after each input.

However, if there is a `printf()` statement inside the loop, it no longer ignores the newline character.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// copy input to output; 1st version
int main()
{
    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        putchar(c);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

The input and output in the terminal looks like this.

```
j
j


b
b


asdf
a
s
d
f


ashdfn
a
s
h
d
f
n
```

It echoes the newline character, which was used to be ignored in the previous situation.

Could you tell me why there is a difference and how does it behave exactly?

Comment: I don't see any ignoring newlines going on here.

Comment: i guess what he is trying to say is, why 2 newline chars are printed, while he expected only one from the printf

Answer (score 2):

In first case, it reads one character - `getchar()` and prints it - `putchar()`, so there is not newline or `'\n'` after each character. The newline is the one you entered with enter key press.

While in 2nd case, you have `printf("\n")` which prints new line after every character is printed - through `putchar()`.

Comment: but it seems he does not understand why is he getting two newlines printed, instead of one from printf, while when there was no printf there was no newline

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

`getchar` reads a character at a time. When you input `123` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key then this input goes to the C standard buffer with one more character `\n` (generated on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key). Now from there `getchar` reads a character at a time and rest of the characters in input stream left behind for the next call of `getchar`.
Now, to answer your question I am going to explain it with a simple program;

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
     int c, b;

     c = getchar();
     putchar(c);

     b = getchar();
     putchar(b);

     b = getchar();
     putchar(b);
 }
```

Giving the input `123`, the input stream of the buffer would be

```
123\n
```

Having four `char`s; `'1'`, `'2'`, `'3'` and `'\n'`.
First `getchar` reads `1` and then `putchar` output this character. Now the buffer have `23\n`. Next call of `getchar` reads `2` and next to it will read `3`. Finally `\n` is left behind for the next call of `getchar`. Hence the output will be

```
123
```

Now inputting the character one by one as in your first example. On passing `j` you are passing `j\n` to the buffer. First call of `getchar` will read `j` and is `putchar` output this on screen. Next call will read `\n` and `putchar` print this out on the screen but the effect is not seen to you until the read of next character. On third call of `getchar`, `b` is read but this time it goes to the next line on the output screen. This is because of the `\n` character read previously by `getchar`. Finally `\n` is left behind in the buffer for next call of `getchar`.

Now coming to your first example

```
#include <stdio.h>

// copy input to output; 1st version
int main()
{
    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
    {
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

This will work similarly as stated above.

Now coming to your second example

```
#include <stdio.h>

// copy input to output; 1st version
int main()
{
    int c;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
    {
        putchar(c);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

This is printing two newlines after each of character but supposed to print a single character, right?

It is printing what it should! This is because it is printing a newline not only for characters `j`, `b`...etc but also for newline character `\n`. Take simple input `j\n`, `b\n`.
On first call of `getchar`, `j` is read and printed with a newline by `printf` then on next call `\n` is printed along with a newline and the output looks like

```
j
    //The newline printed by printf along with j    
    //The newline printed by printf along with \n 
b
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not echoing the newline. `getchar()` is buffered input.  Also, `getchar()` is of echoing type. The control will wait until you press `Enter` key from the keyboard.

If you do

`abcde`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

since `getchar()` is of echoing type, it reads single `char` from the buffer until it encounters `newline` and the same `char` is echoed. The `putchar()` prints the received `char` on the terminal. The newline which is being output is entered by you when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The same thing happens in the second case, but one extra line is added because of `printf`.

Comment: but 2 newlines are getting printed, instead of one from printf

Answer (score 0):

Check http://ideone.com/H2kqBq

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int c;

while((c = getchar()) != EOF)
{
    putchar(c);
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

The output is not as you have specified here.

The behaviour of getchar() and putchar() is consistent

Comment: This is the second case of the OP. You misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion what is happening is, when you enter a character at the terminal, suppose `'a'` and then press `Enter`, actually `two characters` are getting buffered in the input stream

```
'a' and '\n'
```

so the `loop` runs twice to `putchar these two characters`, that is why your next input starts at new line

(you may check that by using:

```
if(c!='\n') putchar(c);
```

this will cause the '\n' not to be printed and you would input on the same line)

when you add `printf("\n")`, it will also be printed twice because the loop will still run two times as there are two characters in the input stream.

so you will get

```
a
(newline from printf)
```

in the `first iteration` of the loop

```
(newline from input buffer)
(newline from printf)
```

in the `second iteration`

Comment: The two newline is not because of `(newline from input buffer)
(newline from printf)`.

Comment: I guess it is. Try checking c for enter just before putchar as in the answer.

Comment: The loop iterates twice. Even in tje actual example it iterates twice and would print the entered char anf then \n . That is why you are able to input from the next line