# Using getchar() in a while loop, prints a statement twice.. how?

Tags: c

I have a very simple program like this

```
int main()
{
    int opt;
    int n;
    int flag = 1;
    while(flag)
    {
        printf("m inside while.Press c to continue\n");
        if((opt = getchar())== 'c')
        {
            printf("choose a number\n");
            scanf(" %d",&n);
            switch(n)
            {
            case 0:
                printf("m zero\n");
                break;
            case 1:
               printf("entered one\n");
               break;
            case 3:
               printf("m exit\n");
               flag = 0;
               break;
            }
            printf("m broke\n");
        }
    }
    printf("m out\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I get output like this:

```
m inside while.Press c to continue
c
choose a number
1
entered one
m broke
m inside while.Press c to continue
m inside while.Press c to continue
c
choose a number
```

My doubt is why "m inside while.Press c to continue" gets printed twice after every loop??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(flag)
{
    printf("m inside while.Press c to continue\n");
    while((opt=getchar()) != '\n') {
    if(opt == 'c')
    {
        printf("choose a number\n");
        scanf(" %d",&n);
        switch(n)
        {
        case 0:
            printf("m zero\n");
            break;
        case 1:
           printf("entered one\n");
           break;
        case 3:
           printf("m exit\n");
           flag = 0;
           break;
        }
        printf("m broke\n");
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is because of `\n` character left behind by previous `scanf`. When you input a number and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, an additional `\n` character passed to the standard input buffer. `scanf` reads that nuber leaving behind `\n` in the buffer. On next iteration of loop `getchar` reads `\n` before pressing any character by you and hence `m inside while.Press c to continue` printed twice as `\n` is not `c`.
Place this snippet of code just after the `scanf` statement in your `while` loop to eat up the newline characters

```
while(getchar() != '\n');
```

This will eat up any number of `\n`.
For more detailed explanation on the behavior of `getchar` read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20773462/2455888).
You final code should be

```
 int main()
{
    int opt;
    int n;
    int flag = 1;
    while(flag)
    {
        printf("m inside while.Press c to continue\n");
        if((opt = getchar())== 'c')
        {
            printf("choose a number\n");
            scanf(" %d",&n);
            while(getchar() != '\n');
            switch(n)
            {
            case 0:
                printf("m zero\n");
                break;
            case 1:
               printf("entered one\n");
               break;
            case 3:
               printf("m exit\n");
               flag = 0;
               break;
            }
            printf("m broke\n");
        }
    }
    printf("m out\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After scanf reads the input there is a `'\n'` still in the buffer you have to clear it otherwise it will be readed by getchar in the next time and as it's `!= 'c'` it will prompt again:

Try this :

```
        printf("choose a number\n");
        scanf(" %d",&n);
        char c;
        while (c = getchar != '\n' && c != EOF);  // clear the buffer
```