# specifying getchar() to Yes / No response before proceeding

Tags: c, loops, scanf, getchar

I'm having some trouble getting nailing down some code to specify the user input to be; n, N, y or Y.

If the user inputs anything other than above it results in a request for re-entry.

I've moved this bit of code around - **while (response != 'n' | 'N' | 'y' | 'Y') {** code up and down and this has indicated it's not providing my anticipated result.

I've tried a few combinations with scanf but that looks to be only able to be able to be defined once in a loop to = response.  Getchar is currently promoting twice, the first key entry and the enter key.

I had hoped something like this would work but it has not.

```
if (response != 'n' || response != 'N' || response != 'y'|| response != 'Y') {
```

I think it might be the method I'm trying to approach this problem with combined with some basic issues understanding what you can actually do with these commands.

Some searching here and it seems to indicate to avoid scanf and getchar at any opportunity but this is all I've been shown so far.

I'm also struggling to understand how to transition from the first Y/N loop to the second loop while > if > while.

Apologies there's quite a few questions but 3 hours and I'm burning time.

Any advice on what's not right and what to read again would be appreciated.

````
 /* Play game yes / no. */
 printf("Would you like to play [y|n]?\n");
 response = getchar();

 /* If response is not "Y" or "N" expected */
 while (response != 'n' | 'N' | 'y' | 'Y') {
 printf("Please enter either 'y' or 'n'.");
 response = getchar();
 }

 /* If response is "no" exit program */
 if (response == 'n' || response == 'N') {
     printf("No worries... another time perhaps... :)\n\n");
     exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
     /* While loop to continue game */
     while (response == 'y' || response == 'Y') {
 ```
````

Comment: `while (response != 'n' | 'N' | 'y' | 'Y') {` doesn't do what you think it does...

Comment: while (response != ('n','y')) {

Seems to allow the Y entry but not the N. Am I correct that (!=) is does not equal?

Comment: You really should read a tutorial on the C language.  You seem to be making wild guesses about many things, most of which are incorrect.  Do you know what `x | y` does?  Do you know what `(x, y)` does?  These are basic C operators, and you have no idea what they do.

Comment: Try drawing a truth table for `response != 'n' || response != 'N'` and you'll see what's wrong.

Comment: @Tom Karzes I'm learning and using a practical approach as that's how I best learn. You might be someone who can read and just do. Congratulations.

I'm actually pretty impressed with what I've got done so far. You comment was sadly not all that helpful.

Comment: @desmo Tom is correct though. Just blindly guessing won't take you very far. When you're doing `response != 'n' | 'N' | 'y' | 'Y'` it's fairly obvious that you have no clue what the `|` operator actually does.

Comment: @desmo And a word of advice. Don't assume malicious intent from people spending their unpaid spare time to help you. What Tom said is actually good advice.

Answer (score 0):

For the next person that comes looking for a similar answer and equally got little value from the unpaid professionals seeking reputation.

I was shown another library that gave me a few options to simplify the problem.

#include <ctype.h>

This allowed me to reduce any users capital entries to lower case to make the next lines of code easier to handle. This will be helpful with less than perfect understanding of the C operators like I have.

// eat up the new line code will fix the double print issue with Getchar()

[A thank you to the previous thread on that issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801854/using-getchar-in-a-while-loop-prints-a-statement-twice-how)

```
/* If response is not "Y" or "N" as expected prompt user to enter again */
response = tolower(response); // reduces user capital entry complexity
while (response != 'y' && response != 'n'){
printf("Please enter either 'y' or 'n'.");
response = tolower(response); // reduces user capital entry complexity
response = getchar();
while (getchar() != '\n'); // eat up the new line
```